# Adding and using an executable file in iOS at runtime

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Suppose, I have some external executable file(call it a `.swift` file) that are not linked with the xcode project at compile time. That means, I did not have any of those files in my project tree when built the project.

For an example, lets say I have a file called `exc.swift`. This file was not included while I built the project.

Is there any way that I can execute that executable (the `exc.swift`) file at runtime?

In android there is a way by using `DexClassLoader` class. That class is responsible for `executing code not installed as part of an application.`

The documentation for that class is [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/dalvik/system/DexClassLoader.html).

Is there an iOS equivalent version of this? or in any way is this achievable?

Answer (score 0):

If you are hoping to distribute the app that you are writing, then this is an absolute no-no. The app store review guidelines clearly state **"Apps that install or launch other executable code will be rejected"** so no app that exhibits this functionality will ever get onto the app store. You may be able to find or devise some kind of hack or workaround to get this kind of thing to work, but it will only ever be for your own amusement.

Comment: No distribution or publishing or anything. I need it for personal use. I just need to know if it is possible. As you said, for personal amusement only :D